# How to instantiate a randomly picked ScriptableObject?

Tags: c#, random, instantiation, scriptable-object

Im new to Unity and c#, I've been making a turn based game following one of Brackeys tutorial and i've added scriptable objects to it. Im looking to instantiate a random enemy everytime a fight starts.

Here's the lines that should be useful : [ImageOfMyCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G68aK.png)
[image]
The resources.LoadAll("Enemies") seems to work since I made 3 scriptable objects and the debug log also says 3.

Im really struggling past this to then shuffle allEnemies and instantite the randomly picked one.

Any help and guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get for the `Instantiate` is because you pass a number instead the object that you want to instantiate, you can read more about it here: [Object.Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

What you can do is the following:

```
var randomRange = Random.Range(0,allEnemies.Length);
GameObject enemyGO = Instatiate(allEnemies[randomRange],playerBattleStation) as GameObject;
```